# How to check if an element is off-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, zk

I need to check with jQuery if a DIV element is not falling off-screen. The elements are visible and displayed according CSS attributes, but they could be intentionally placed off-screen by:

```
position: absolute; 
left: -1000px; 
top: -1000px;
```

I could not use the jQuery `:visible` selector as the element has a non-zero height and width.

I am not doing anything fancy. This absolute position placement is the way my [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) framework implements the hide/show of some widgets.

Comment: I gave an answer to this as well on this 'duplicate' question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen/5354536#5354536

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Depends on what your definition of "offscreen" is. Is that within the viewport, or within the defined boundaries of your page?

Using [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) you can easily detect whether or not your element is within the boundries of your viewport (i.e. onscreen or offscreen):

```
jQuery.expr.filters.offscreen = function(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
           (rect.x + rect.width) < 0 
             || (rect.y + rect.height) < 0
             || (rect.x > window.innerWidth || rect.y > window.innerHeight)
         );
};
```

You could then use that in several ways:

```
// returns all elements that are offscreen
$(':offscreen');

// boolean returned if element is offscreen
$('div').is(':offscreen');
```

Comment: I liked this, but it breaks if your element is inside a scrollable container -- an element at the bottom of a 2-screen-tall DIV will always be "offscreen" since the window height is less than the offsetTop of the element.

Comment: @scurker I could not get this to work. Here is my SO question (with jsFiddle) about the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004098/extend-jquery-to-create-custom-filter-re-element-outside-viewport

Comment: am I wrong here to think that this won't if el has positioned parent (absolute or relative) before the body?

Comment: @fekirimalek You are correct, I've updated the example to account for that

Comment: @scurker , cool look much better now, and helped me to reduce 2 lines if condition into 1 line. and I think it's cross browser too.. hope so anyway..

Comment: I believe this returns true even if the element is partially off the screen.  How would I detect completely off screen?

Comment: Note that currently (Jan 2017) this will not work at least on Chrome, because Element.getBoundingClientRect() has properties top, right, bottom and left instead of x and y.

Comment: @Asu That's interesting, because according to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/geometry-1/#dom-domrect) it should contain both `x` and `y` values. I suppose you could swap `left` and `right` respectively, but I'm not sure what's changed in Chrome.

Comment: what about adding  (rect.x + rect.width > window.innerWidth || rect.y + rect.height > window.innerHeight) in the conditions of the functions

Comment: Based on your answer, I created a variant which returns `true` for both partially or fully offscreen elements, here: [https://pastebin.com/CqgWvf1a](https://pastebin.com/CqgWvf1a)

Answer (score 17):

There's a [jQuery plugin here](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) which allows users to test whether an element falls within the visible viewport of the browser, taking the browsers scroll position into account.

```
$('#element').visible();
```

You can also check for partial visibility:

```
$('#element').visible( true);
```

One drawback is that it only works with vertical positioning / scrolling, although it should be easy enough to add horizontal positioning into the mix.

Comment: This is a VERY light weight plugin. I was able to get a fixed navbar on scroll up and working responsively within minutes of adding it. Great suggestion.

Comment: This plugin is very light and quite easy to implement. Solved the issue I had with the sub-menus.

Answer (score 9):

No need for a plugin to check if outside of view port.

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
var d = $(document).scrollTop();

$.each($("div"),function(){
    p = $(this).position();
    //vertical
    if (p.top > h + d || p.top > h - d){
        console.log($(this))
    }
    //horizontal
    if (p.left < 0 - $(this).width() || p.left > w){
        console.log($(this))
    }
});
```

Comment: This would work if you used `$(this).offset` instead of `$this.position`.  Right now it's just calculating the distance from it's parent, which could be a div that wraps it perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

Well... I've found some issues in every proposed solution here.

- You should be able to choose if you want **entire element** to be on screen or **just any part of it**
- Proposed solutions **fails if element is higher/wider than window** and kinda *covers* browser window.

Here is my solution that include `jQuery` `.fn` instance function and `expression`. I've created more variables inside my function than I could, but for complex logical problem I like to divide it into smaller, clearly named pieces.

I'm using `getBoundingClientRect` method that returns element position relatively to the viewport **so I don't need to care about scroll position**

**Useage**:

```
$(".some-element").filter(":onscreen").doSomething();
$(".some-element").filter(":entireonscreen").doSomething();
$(".some-element").isOnScreen(); // true / false
$(".some-element").isOnScreen(true); // true / false (partially on screen)
$(".some-element").is(":onscreen"); // true / false (partially on screen)
$(".some-element").is(":entireonscreen"); // true / false
```

**Source**:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(partial){

    //let's be sure we're checking only one element (in case function is called on set)
    var t = $(this).first();

    //we're using getBoundingClientRect to get position of element relative to viewport
    //so we dont need to care about scroll position
    var box = t[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    //let's save window size
    var win = {
        h : $(window).height(),
        w : $(window).width()
    };

    //now we check against edges of element

    //firstly we check one axis
    //for example we check if left edge of element is between left and right edge of scree (still might be above/below)
    var topEdgeInRange = box.top >= 0 && box.top <= win.h;
    var bottomEdgeInRange = box.bottom >= 0 && box.bottom <= win.h;

    var leftEdgeInRange = box.left >= 0 && box.left <= win.w;
    var rightEdgeInRange = box.right >= 0 && box.right <= win.w;


    //here we check if element is bigger then window and 'covers' the screen in given axis
    var coverScreenHorizontally = box.left <= 0 && box.right >= win.w;
    var coverScreenVertically = box.top <= 0 && box.bottom >= win.h;

    //now we check 2nd axis
    var topEdgeInScreen = topEdgeInRange && ( leftEdgeInRange || rightEdgeInRange || coverScreenHorizontally );
    var bottomEdgeInScreen = bottomEdgeInRange && ( leftEdgeInRange || rightEdgeInRange || coverScreenHorizontally );

    var leftEdgeInScreen = leftEdgeInRange && ( topEdgeInRange || bottomEdgeInRange || coverScreenVertically );
    var rightEdgeInScreen = rightEdgeInRange && ( topEdgeInRange || bottomEdgeInRange || coverScreenVertically );

    //now knowing presence of each edge on screen, we check if element is partially or entirely present on screen
    var isPartiallyOnScreen = topEdgeInScreen || bottomEdgeInScreen || leftEdgeInScreen || rightEdgeInScreen;
    var isEntirelyOnScreen = topEdgeInScreen && bottomEdgeInScreen && leftEdgeInScreen && rightEdgeInScreen;

    return partial ? isPartiallyOnScreen : isEntirelyOnScreen;

};

$.expr.filters.onscreen = function(elem) {
  return $(elem).isOnScreen(true);
};

$.expr.filters.entireonscreen = function(elem) {
  return $(elem).isOnScreen(true);
};
```

Comment: I get make_footer_down.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined when trying to use ur functions there.

Comment: Hi Lurr... I tried with $("#divId").isOnScreen(true); where 'divId' was offscreen and it returned me 'false'; so, I feel its working

Answer (score 8):

Although the original poster has asked for a JQuery solution, they have also added a JavaScript tag on the question which permits adding this more modern solution as well:

**TLDR:**
Use the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Here are two sandboxes I've made both in vanilla JavaScript and in React to show this in working examples:

1. [Vanilla JavaScript example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-snow-nmoz7t?file=/index.html)
2. [React example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-glitter-8sb7l0?file=/src/App.js) (uses the react-intersection-observer NPM module)

**A bit longer answer:**  It's been more than 10 years since this question was asked and at that time using these JQuery solutions made sense, but today we don't need JQuery for such need anymore:

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport.

It's very easy to use, first create an observer and pass it what you want to do when it's triggered (a callback function), and also optionally pass an options object too, e.g., in the case of this question, we'll need the threshold option with value of 1 to make sure the element is completely within the viewport, and if not, then we'll know that it's "offscreen":

```
const doable = () => {
  //do something
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(doable, { threshold: 1 });
```

Now call the `observe()` method of it and pass the element you want to observe to it:

```
observer.observe(observee)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of late but this plugin should work. http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

```
$('p.inview').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
if (visible) {
  $(this).text('You can see me!');
} else {
  $(this).text('Hidden again');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Get the distance from the top of the given element
- Add the height of the same given element. This will tell you the total number from the top of the screen to the end of the given element.
- Then all you have to do is subtract that from total document height

  ```
  jQuery(function () {
      var documentHeight = jQuery(document).height();
      var element = jQuery('#you-element');
      var distanceFromBottom = documentHeight - (element.position().top + element.outerHeight(true));
      alert(distanceFromBottom)
  });
  ```

Answer (score -2):

You could check the position of the div using `$(div).position()` and check if the left and top margin properties are less than 0 :

```
if($(div).position().left < 0 && $(div).position().top < 0){
    alert("off screen");
}
```

Comment: What if the div is not negative out of view?