# affect another div after a specific div is no longer visible from scrolling down the page

Tags: jquery

For example: I want to change the background of div.world to blue when the div.hello is no longer in view after scrolling down the page.

Here is the code I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/cJWAr/140/

```
<div id="cat">
<div class="hello">hello</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="world">world</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
   if ($('.hello').is(":visible") ){
    $('.world').addClass('red');       
    }
    else if  ($('.hello').is(":hidden") ){
    $('.world').addClass('blue');  
     }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to get the background of div.world to blue when the div.hello is no longer in view after scrolling down the page. But its not working. I must be doing something wrong or missing something.

Comment: That's not hidden but scrolled up...

Comment: You can use scrollTop functionality to make your logic happen....

Comment: I'm trying to use the :visible selector http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: The element is always *visible* as far as whether its visible or hidden, you need to use Javascript to determine whether it's inside your viewable area or not

Comment: From jquery page: Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero. http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: oh, I see. I'll read up on the scrollTop function

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897289/how-to-check-if-element-is-off-screen

Answer (score 0):

The element is not hidden until you explicitly set its `visibity : hidden`. It's just scrolled down. For your task, you might want to use the [jquery appear plugin](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear). Works like a charm. Once set up, just do -

```
$('.hello').appear(function() { //if the element is visible, change the background to something else
  $('.world').css({'background':'your-background'});
});
```

You can also use the disappear function, if you'd like.

```
$('someselector').on('disappear', function(event, $all_disappeared_elements) {
  // this element is now outside browser viewport
});
```