# How to check if div is visible to user or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically i have a notification in the slide bar which is by default not visible(toggled).When any notification comes , it gets populated in the slidebar and on click of a toggle button slide bar opens from right to left.How can i make sure whether user has viewed a particular notification in slideBar.

something similar to [this link](http://bucketadmin.themebucket.net/#)  i have done.

On click of the toggle on top right the slide bar will open and the notification will be visible .how to know that state ??

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can do something like

```
if($(element).is(':visible')) {
    // Hello
}
```

Comment: The element is visible all the time . It just gets shifted to right when toggled.Thus this might not help ..

Comment: Check here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport solution from @Dan, as recommended.

Comment: This answer may be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897289/how-to-check-if-element-is-off-screen