# Extend jQuery to create custom filter re element outside viewport

Tags: jquery

Found this SO great question/answer re extending jQuery to determine if an element is off screen:

[How to check if an element is off-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897289/how-to-check-if-element-is-off-screen)

Also found this article, but could not use to resolve problem:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dissecting-jquery-filters--net-13954

---

Using scurker's *(accepted answer)* code, this should alert (and hide element) when yellow DIV scrolls off screen. It doesn't. Cannot find the problem.

[**jsFiddle** (for those who prefer)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzq85592/)

```
Raw jQuery / CSS / HTML Code (S.O. Embedded):
```

```js
jQuery.expr.filters.offscreen = function(el) {
  return (
              (el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) < 0 
              || (el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) < 0
              || (el.offsetLeft > window.innerWidth || el.offsetTop > window.innerHeight)
         );
};

var d1=0,d2=0,d3=0,dir='dn',cpos=0,lpos=0;
var div1=$('#d1'),div4=$('#d4'),div5=$('#d5');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    cpos = $(window).scrollTop(); //get current scroll position
        div4.html(cpos);
    dir = (cpos>lpos) ? 'dn': 'up'; //get scroll direction
        //div5.html(dir);
    if (dir=='dn'){
        d1 = cpos + (cpos*1.25);
    }else{
        d1 = cpos - (cpos*1.25);
    }
    div1.html(d1); //update pos numbers
    
    div1.dequeue().stop().animate({'top':d1+'px'});
    lpos = cpos; //store for line 6

    div1.is(':offscreen').hide();
    div5.html(  (div1.is(':offscreen')) ? 'yup':'no' );
});
```

```css
html{height:1800px;}
body{background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/500/500') no-repeat center center fixed;background-size:cover;}
.divs{position:fixed;top:0;height:120px;width:60px;}
#d1{background:yellow;}

#d4{background:wheat;left:380px;}
#d5{background:white;left:440px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1" class="divs"></div>
<div id="d4" class="divs"></div><!-- curr window scrollTop -->
<div id="d5" class="divs"></div><!-- curr scroll direction -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Not certain about utilizing `:offscreen` to test for whether element is "offscreen" or not - as mentioned at original [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897628/2801559)

> Depends on what your definition of "offscreen" is. Is that within the
>   viewport, or within the defined boundaries of your page?
>
> It'd be pretty simple to write a check to see if it's offscreen (not
>   taking the viewport into account...)-scurker

At jsfiddle , `div1.is(':offscreen')` appear to return `false` after `:offscreen` element is hidden, resulting in "no" at `div5` `html`. Instead , could utilize jQuery [:hidden Selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) to check if `div1` is `:hidden`

jQuery [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns `Boolean` .

at

`div1.is(':offscreen').hide();`

`.hide()` *not* chained to `this` element ; instead chained to `is()`'s `Boolean` return value ?

Try, updated

```
div1.filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(":offscreen")
}).hide();
// added
// modify `div5` `html` by checking if `div1` is `:hidden`
div5.html( div1.is(':hidden') ? 'yup':'no' );
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/Lzq85592/5/

Comment: That is excellent, but this part still doesn't work: `div5.html(  (div1.is(':offscreen')) ? 'yup':'no' );`  How can I trigger putting that text ("Yes") in div5? *Can you modify your jsFiddle, please?*

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Nice workaround. Full marks. Thanks!