# Bootstrap nav submenu float left or right according to page limits

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a multi-level menu in a project based in Bootstrap and jQuery.
Everything works fine except one thing: When a menu item is placed too much on the right, it's sub-menus exceed the page and are not readable (as shown on the screenshot taken from jsFiddle):

[image: Bootstrap multi level menu]

Is there a way to detect if a submenu (when opened) exceeds the page limit, and if it does, to be placed on the other side of it's parent element?

My code so far is:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO HERE!</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Blog <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog Post</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Search Engines</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Google</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="https://adwords.google.com" target="_blank">Google Adwords</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://analytics.google.com" target="_blank">Google Analytics</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/webmaster/" target="_blank">Webmaster Tools</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.msn.com">MSN</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">All Tags</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
    background-color:rgba(216,216,216,1);
    background-image:none;
    color:#000;
}
.divider{
    background-color:#fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu{
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{
    display:block;
    content: " ";
    float:right;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{
    border-left-color: #555;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{
    float:none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{
    left:100%;
    margin-left:1-0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(e){
    //$(this).next('ul').show();

    //console.log('click');
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
  if($('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('open')){
    console.log('visible');
  }
});
```

Test fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/311mcf23/

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I came across this topic: [How to check if an element is off-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897289/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-off-screen)

As suggested by @Sam Sehnert, I ended up using the plugin that can be found here: https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible

With some minor modifications, the result was exactly what I was looking for!

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO HERE!</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">Blog <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog Post</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Search Engines</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false">Google</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="https://adwords.google.com" target="_blank">Google Adwords</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://analytics.google.com" target="_blank">Google Analytics</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/webmaster/" target="_blank">Webmaster
                                            Tools</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.msn.com">MSN</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">All Tags</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
    background-color:rgba(216,216,216,1);
    background-image:none;
    color:#000;
}
.divider{
    background-color:#fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu{
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{
    display:block;
    content: " ";
    float:right;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{
    border-left-color: #555;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{
    float:none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{
    left:100%;
    margin-left:1-0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
}
.rev{
    left:auto !important;
    right:100% !important;
    top:8px !important;
    margin-right:-12px !important;
}
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
/**
 * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
 *
 * @author Sam Sehnert
 * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
 *       the user visible viewport of a web browser.
 *       only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
 */
$.fn.visible = function (partial, hidden, direction, container) {
    if (this.length < 1) return;

    var $t = this.length > 1 ? this.eq(0) : this,
    isContained = typeof container !== "undefined" && container !== null,
    $w = isContained ? $(container) : $(window),
    wPosition = isContained ? $w.position() : 0,
    t = $t.get(0),
    vpWidth = $w.outerWidth(),
    vpHeight = $w.outerHeight(),
    direction = direction ? direction : "both",
    clientSize = hidden === true ? t.offsetWidth * t.offsetHeight : true;

    if (typeof t.getBoundingClientRect === "function") {
    // Use this native browser method, if available.
    var rec = t.getBoundingClientRect(),
        tViz = isContained
        ? rec.top - wPosition.top >= 0 && rec.top < vpHeight + wPosition.top
        : rec.top >= 0 && rec.top < vpHeight,
        bViz = isContained
        ? rec.bottom - wPosition.top > 0 &&
            rec.bottom <= vpHeight + wPosition.top
        : rec.bottom > 0 && rec.bottom <= vpHeight,
        lViz = isContained
        ? rec.left - wPosition.left >= 0 &&
            rec.left < vpWidth + wPosition.left
        : rec.left >= 0 && rec.left < vpWidth,
        rViz = isContained
        ? rec.right - wPosition.left > 0 &&
            rec.right < vpWidth + wPosition.left
        : rec.right > 0 && rec.right <= vpWidth,
        vVisible = partial ? tViz || bViz : tViz && bViz,
        hVisible = partial ? lViz || rViz : lViz && rViz;

    if (direction === "both") return clientSize && vVisible && hVisible;
        else if (direction === "vertical") return clientSize && vVisible;
        else if (direction === "horizontal") return clientSize && hVisible;
    } else {
        var viewTop = isContained ? 0 : wPosition,
        viewBottom = viewTop + vpHeight,
        viewLeft = $w.scrollLeft(),
        viewRight = viewLeft + vpWidth,
        position = $t.position(),
        _top = position.top,
        _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
        _left = position.left,
        _right = _left + $t.width(),
        compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom,
        compareLeft = partial === true ? _right : _left,
        compareRight = partial === true ? _left : _right;

    if (direction === "both")
        return (
        !!clientSize &&
        compareBottom <= viewBottom &&
        compareTop >= viewTop &&
        compareRight <= viewRight &&
        compareLeft >= viewLeft
        );
    else if (direction === "vertical")
        return (
        !!clientSize && compareBottom <= viewBottom && compareTop >= viewTop
        );
    else if (direction === "horizontal")
        return (
        !!clientSize && compareRight <= viewRight && compareLeft >= viewLeft
        );
    }
};
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[data-toggle=dropdown]").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("open");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");

        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
        if ($(this).parent("li").hasClass("open")) {
            if (!$(this).next("ul").visible()) {
            console.log("not visible");
            $(this).next("ul").addClass("rev");
            }
        } else {
            $(this).next("ul").removeClass("rev");
        }
        }
    });
});
```

The outcome can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/captain_theo/311mcf23/2/

Hope that helps others with similar problems.

Theo

Answer (score 0):

try removing this code from the css

```
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{
top:0;
left:100%;
margin-top:-6px;
margin-left:-1px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
```

Comment: I tried that, but then the submenus fall right underneath the parent element -which is not good as this may confuse the user

Answer (score 0):

It would not be easy to detect when there is a collision with the viewport. I'd recommend moving the submenus left like this..

```
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:-99%;max-width:180px;margin-top:-6px;margin-right:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:left;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 5px 5px 0;border-right-color:#999;margin-top:5px;margin-right:10px;}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:0px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-menu-right {margin-left:0;}
```

http://www.bootply.com/pho42x2it2

Comment: Well, it is just for design purposes that I am trying to avoid that... After all for those of us who are used to reading left-to-right, this suggested alignment can be a bit awkward... That's why I would only like to do that IF the given element exceeded the viewport.