# Get the div of current scroll offset of UIWebView

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have two different HTML files, two different `UIWebViews` & a `UISegmentControl`. On `segmentChanged`, I had displayed the `WebView` by loading a HTML file. 
Both HTML files contains common sections only the section content is changed. Now I want to implement the functionality that, when user reads `section 1.1` of first `WebView` & clicks `Segment` for loading second `WebView`, then the second `WebView` needs to `scroll` upto the `section 1.1` which he reads in first `WebView` and viceversa. Also there are n number of sections.
I used following javacript but it needs the parameter of current `div id`. But on `scroll`, how can I get the current visible `div id`. I had given the `id` for each `div`.

```
function pointInView(id)
{
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    divid.scrollIntoView(true);
    return false;
}
```

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot to get the div id from current `scroll offset`but didn't get the solution for it. So I go with the other option that, stored the start & end offsets of each section in both files. So I had created one look-up table in database & stored the start & end offsets of each section in both files.

ex. When user `scrolls` the first `webview` to `section 1.1` & clicks the switch to open the second `webview`, then I `scrolled` the second `webview` to the section 1.1 in the second file.

Answer (score 2):

I think jquery might be able to come to your rescue.

Could you use jQuery, since it's cross-browser compatible?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen
```

Check out answer form BenM

Comment: The above link is basically for JQuery but I want it in Javascript.

Comment: The same link has a javascript implementation show below the jquery one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a db entry for that. Just catch the click event via something like

```
$('.action').click(function(){
    document.location = yourSecondFIleLocation+'?offset = ' + $('selectorDiv').detOffsetFromParentDiv(); //or get the scroll offset from the page.
});
```

and catch it on the second page either with php or jQuery to scroll to it.

Heck that is even achievable if you put in your code the paragraph marks and link correctly to them.

Comment: I am not clicking anywhere in the webview, just scrolls it.

Comment: Then it is possible to. just add the event listener on te scrollbar. and get the position when swithichng to the other window.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below,

To scroll any scroll view at any position we set the content offset of the scroll view.
To solve your problem we have two solutions,

1. In your case when user is viewing the first Web view, save the content offset of the first web view in any variable like below
   CGFloat offset = webView1.scrollView.contentOffset.y; Then when you
   open the second web view then provide this offset value to second
   web view scroll offset.
2. Set
   webView1.scrollView.contentOffset=webView2.scrollView.contentOffset
       or vice versa according to your need

I hope this will help you.

Comment: But the offsets are not same in both the files. Only sections are same.