# jQuery queues fadeIn() on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `fadeIn` on scroll seems to be triggering every time I  scroll which is what I want. But this queues up the animation and ends up running well after the user has stopped scrolling.

I have tried using the `.stop(true, true)` function but I believe this does not work on a `if` or `else` statement.

My code so far:

```
if($('.icon').isOnScreen()){
    $('.icon').fadeIn("slow");  
} else {
    $('.icon').fadeOut("slow"); 
};
```

I have tried below but this does not work

```
if($('.icon').isOnScreen()){
    $('.icon').stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");  
} else {
    $('.icon').stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow"); 
};
```

Comment: Try calling `$('.icon').fadeIn('slow')` only when `$('.icon')` is not visible yet. This way you can avoid it being called everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, thanks all

```
if($('.box').isOnScreen()){
    if($('.icon').isOnScreen()){
        $('.icon').fadeIn("slow");      
    } else {
        $('.icon').fadeOut("slow"); 
    }
} else {
    $('.icon').stop().fadeOut("slow");  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried his?

```
var isfadeId;
if($('.icon').isOnScreen()){
   if(!isfadeId) $('.icon').fadeIn("slow");
   isfadeId = true;
} else {
   if(isfadeId) $('.icon').fadeOut("slow"); 
   isfadeId = false;
};
```

Comment: Although Brent's answer didn't work, kindly check out this two links as this is somewhat a similar question. [link #1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen), [link #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)