# How to not move page if html element is on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

*I don't use jQuery. Can this be solved without it ?*

I have only 1 HTML / JavaScript / (CSS) page. It contains links that reference html elements on the very same page. The page has a automatic vertical scrollbar because it is long. I need my event handler for link clicks **to check if the referenced element is on the screen** at the moment of the click. If it is there the page should not change position. Is that possible and how ?

1. check if on screen
2. don't move page

This code is a simple example that the page jumps so that the "hello world 2" is on the very top of the browser window.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
            function onLinkClick(id)
            { }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="id1">hello world 1</div>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id="id2">hello world 2</div>
        <a href="#id2" onclick="onLinkClick('id2')">link</a>
        <div id="id3">hello world 3</div>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look into a possibly duplicate question here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Checking for visibility is one part of my question.

Comment: @mini-me If your callback function return `false`, then the event will be stopped, and the browser will not scroll the page. In you callback function, check if the element is already visible - if it is return `false`, otherwise return `true`.

Comment: @mini-me It is NOT wrong, returning `false` from a callback will indeed prevent the default behavior - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event) is some more on that. It is however true that you can call `preventDefault()` on the event, to achieve it as well - doing so is actually a more modern way of achieving it. Talking modern ways of doing things, it might be worth mentioning that there are more modern ways of [attaching event-listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) as well

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I'm not an expert on JavaScript so if you try to help a newbie you should not leave out important details. I've never seen the quotes (onClick='') as a function and the detail that it is one is worth something and should not be left out (except you like to play games in comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by myself (yes with some help of the referenced duplicate question). Using **no** jQuery:

```
function isElementVisible(element)
{
    var posTop = 0;
    var temp = element;
    while (temp)
    {
        posTop += temp.offsetTop;
        temp = temp.offsetParent;
    }
    var posBottom = posTop + element.offsetHeight;
    var visibleTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    var visibleBottom = visibleTop + window.innerHeight;
    return ((posBottom >= visibleTop) && (posTop <= visibleBottom));
}

function onLinkClick(id)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (isElementVisible(x))
        // prevent page to be scrolled up or down
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried

> getElementByTagName()  ???