# style.clip is empty -- need to know if part of div is visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, clip

I have a simple div.  When the browser (Firefox version 26) window is shrunk, the viewable area of the div is partly invisible.

I need to find out when a specific location (the right middle edge of the div, **for example**) is visible.

Much to my surprise, the following yields an empty value -- no string, no rect, nothing.  Cannot figure out why.  The docs and examples I've see indicate that style.clip should return a string with the clipping rect's top, right, bottom, left values  *of the visible part of the element.*

For example, even W3schools.com [shows that](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_clip.asp).

Here's my code.

```
 window.onresize = function(event) 
 {
   console.log("Hi, we're about to get the clip rect for myDiv.");
   console.log("myDiv clip rect is: " + document.getElementById('myDiv').style.clip);
 }


   <div id="myDiv" style="height: 99%; display: inline-block; width: 99%;
             background-color: red"></div>
```

I can see the div (red background).
But style.clip for myDiv is *empty*, no string, nothing.  My "!DOCTYPE html" is at the top of the page.   Cannot figure this out, probably something simple though.

Any ideas?
By the way:  will not be using any javascript libraries here, just pure natural javascript.

Comment: If you didn't set a `rect` style, there's nothing to return? I think you're just misunderstanding this, it does not magically return values for what parts of an element is visible unless you specifically set the `rect` style.

Comment: I think you're saying that part of the div is outside the browser window - in other words, if you enlarged the browser, the div would be completely visible. If that's the case, this thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when shrinking the browser window's width, even though the browser window's horizontal scrollbar appeared, scrolling to the right yielded an empty region even though there was data there.  I fixed this by setting a hardcoded width for the div -- also found I could programmatically increase the width of the div as the 'scrollWidth' increased -- either method worked.