# how can I start playing my video in html5 when user scrolls to it?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm creating a webpage and I have a mp4 video there:

```
<video class="video--app" id="myVideo" autoplay="" muted="" preload="auto">
    <source src="./img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I also wrote a part of JS code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
        }, 1500);
```

and that works almost ok, the video starts playing after 1,5 second. But I would like to change it and start playing video when it first appears on the screen - basically when user scrolls to it. Can you give me any hint how should I modify my JS code to achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/1697755) has a function for checking whether an element is in view:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    return isVisible;
}
```

So after the user has scrolled, you could check if the video is in view, and if so, start it:

```
var videoEl = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var videoWasStarted = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(videoEl) && !videoWasStarted) {
    videoWasStarted = true;
    videoEl.play();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked for me! One more question here - is there a way of playing the video only once and then do not play it at all?

Comment: @user3766930 Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery for easability. Use Scroll Function so that when user comes Scrolling to your Video it will trigger the video to Play.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(wScroll > $('#myVideo').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        $('#myVideo').get(0).play()
    }
});
```

Remember to add jquery library in your HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could include jQuery to make life easier for you.
My suggestion is adapted from this post: [check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen)

```
function isOnScreen(element)
{
    var curPos = element.offset();
    var curTop = curPos.top;
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    return (curTop > screenHeight) ? false : true;
}
if(isOnScreen($('#myVideo'))) { $('#myVideo').play();};
```

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, do you agree with me or are you being sarcastic? Personally, I get tired of typing "document.getElementById"

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫,hahaha  just saw your link - that's great!

Comment: IMO I don't think tired of typing that is a legit reason to include the entire jQuery library, especially when `document.querySelectorAll` already provides a native implementation with arguably better performance.

Comment: Yea it's a really funny link that I always like to share.