# How to evaluate javascript code from Behat to Selenium properly?

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, behat, mink

I have following code (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen)) in my custom step definition:

```
    $js = <<<JS

    function checkVisibility( elm, evalType ) {
        evalType = evalType || "visible";

        var vpH = jQuery(window).height(), // Viewport Height
            st = jQuery(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
            y = jQuery(elm).offset().top,
            elementHeight = jQuery(elm).height();

        if (evalType === "visible") return ((y < (vpH + st)) && (y > (st - elementHeight)));
        if (evalType === "above") return ((y < (vpH + st)));
    }  

    var el = document.querySelector("$locator");
    return checkVisibility(el, "visible");
JS;


    $result = $this->getSession()->evaluateScript($js);
```

Similar code is working well in chrome console, but in Behat context `$result` is always null.

I'm using Behat: `3.0.15` with Selenium `3.4` and PhantomJS as a browser.

In general it seems that if I passing one-line code it's working ok. No matter what is inside my function, I've always null, so below code also result with null:

```
    $js = <<<JS

    function checkVisibility() {
      return true;
    }  

   // var el = document.querySelector("$locator");
    return checkVisibility();
JS;
```

Comment: Why just not use `isVisible` method? have you tried and is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I have something like bellow that works:

```
    $js = <<<JS

    (function myFunction() {
      //function content
    })()
JS;
```

You should wait for the element before to make sure the element is visible.

Also to get the response you should have something like:

```
$result = $this->getSession()->evaluateScript("return $js");
```

Comment: And when you put `return true` to the `myFunction()` you get `true` on PHP also?

Comment: Yes, I get `true` in PHP also. I am using page objects and I have something like `$this->getDriver()->evaluateScript("return $function");` in a page object.

Comment: So it's something wrong with my environment. In my case `$result` is always `null` :/ Are you using phantomjs as browser?

Comment: No, I am using chrome.