# Add videos to Wordpress with autoplay and stop on scroll

Tags: wordpress, video

I need to insert in my Wordpress page a video uploaded in Media Library. This video has to autoplay when is in browser view and has to stop on user scroll.

I tried to use  tag with autoplay function and it's ok. Then I have add to my js folder (in theme folder) a file with some Javascript code in order to add stop on scroll function. I suspect that the code I have tried if fine only with YouTube link.

This is the code I have tried

```js
//play when video is visible
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"), fraction = 0.8;

function checkScroll() {

  for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var video = videos[i];

    var x = 0,
        y = 0,
        w = video.width,
        h = video.height,
        r, //right
        b, //bottom 
        visibleX, visibleY, visible,
        parent;


    parent = video;
    while (parent && parent !== document.body) {
      x += parent.offsetLeft;
      y += parent.offsetTop;
      parent = parent.offsetParent;
    }

    r = x + parseInt(w);
    b = y + parseInt(h);


    visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
    visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));


    visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);


    if (visible > fraction) {
      playVideo();
    } else {
      pauseVideo();

    }
  }

};


var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
};

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);

    //check at least once so you don't have to wait for scrolling for the    video to start
    window.addEventListener('load', checkScroll, false);
};


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      //console.log("event played");
    } else {
      //console.log("event paused");
    }
};

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
};

function playVideo() {
  player.playVideo();
};

function pauseVideo() {
  player.pauseVideo();
};
```

Using a Youtube link the script pause video on scroll but don't autoplay. I expect both autoplay and pause on scroll using a video from my Wordpress media library

Answer (score 0):

```js
var autoPlayVideo = document.getElementById("ocScreencapVideo");
    autoPlayVideo.oncanplaythrough = function() {
        autoPlayVideo.muted = true;
        autoPlayVideo.play();
        autoPlayVideo.pause();
        autoPlayVideo.play();
    }
```

```html
<video id="ocScreencapVideo" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" playsinline="playsinline" preload="metadata" data-aos="fade-up">
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6NZfCO5SIk">
    Your browser does not support MP4 Format videos or HTML5 Video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this custom script to your wordpress. You can use plugins like [Simple Custom CSS and JS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/) for adding custom snippets.

Here the function checkVisible is taken from another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    //To check if element is visible
    function checkVisible(elm) {
        var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
        var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
        return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
    }
    
    //To play-pause self-hosted videos in elementor only when it's visible
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $(".elementor-video").each(function (i, obj) {
            if (checkVisible(obj)) {
                obj.play();
            } else
                obj.pause();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using a custom script, you can go with this [plugin][1] provided by Wordpress library to save time and efforts.

Another solution is to use this javascript for autoplay video:

```
https://codepen.io/bloodcrow777/pen/QBVKKy
```

```js
var autoPlayVideo = document.getElementById("ocScreencapVideo");
    autoPlayVideo.oncanplaythrough = function() {
        autoPlayVideo.muted = true;
        autoPlayVideo.play();
        autoPlayVideo.pause();
        autoPlayVideo.play();
    }
```

```html
<video id="ocScreencapVideo" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" playsinline="playsinline" preload="metadata" data-aos="fade-up">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"
          type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support MP4 Format videos or HTML5 Video.
</video>
```

Comment: I can't see Wordpress plugin you link

Comment: Javascript you posted didn't pause the video on user scroll