# Adding class dynamically based on which element is being scrolled past

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a `nav` which contains letters and `sections` which are associated to letters in the `nav`.

When a user scrolls to a `section`, I want to `addClass` `active` to that letter. For example:

- User scrolls to `section` with the `id` of `a`, the `anchor` with the `data-letter` with `a` will be active.

Currently, on scroll, all my letters in the `nav` become active and this is because it's always thinking it's on `section` A.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    
    // step 1: get id of section
    var visible_section = $('section:visible'), id = visible_section.attr('id');
    console.log(id);

    // step 2: add class where id and data-letter match
  $("nav a").removeClass("active");
  $("nav a[data-letter='"+id+"']").addClass("active");
    
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  background: grey;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.nav a.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.sections {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

section {
  padding: 200px 0;
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<main>

  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#a" data-letter="a">A</a>
    <a href="#b" data-letter="b">B</a>
    <a href="#c" data-letter="c">C</a>
    <a href="#d" data-letter="d">D</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="sections">
    <section id="a">A</section>
    <section id="b">B</section>
    <section id="c">C</section>
    <section id="d">D</section>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Use IntersectionObserver API https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618188/15273968

Answer (score 1):

FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5354536/4571790

```js
function isVisible(elm) {
  var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    
    // step 1: get id of section
    var visible_section = $('section:visible'), id="";
    
    // this code will find which section is the first visible
    $(".sections").find("section").each((i,a)=>id==""?(isVisible(a)?id=$(a).attr("id"):id):id);
    $("#result").html(id +" is visible now");
    //console.log(id);

    // step 2: add class where id and data-letter match
  $("nav a").removeClass("active");
  $("nav a[data-letter='"+id+"']").addClass("active");
    
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  background: grey;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.nav a.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.sections {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

section {
  padding: 200px 0;
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<main>

  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#a" data-letter="a">A</a>
    <a href="#b" data-letter="b">B</a>
    <a href="#c" data-letter="c">C</a>
    <a href="#d" data-letter="d">D</a>
    <span id="result"></span>
  </nav>

  <div class="sections">
    <section id="a">A</section>
    <section id="b">B</section>
    <section id="c">C</section>
    <section id="d">D</section>
  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate the `nav` tabs by setting their `data-letter` as you described to `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`:

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="#a" data-letter="a">A</a>
    <a href="#b" data-letter="b">B</a>
    <a href="#c" data-letter="c">C</a>
    <a href="#d" data-letter="d">D</a>
</nav>
```

All your `nav` become active not because it always thinks it's on `a`, but because all `data-letter` are set to `a`.

Comment: Apologies, that was an oversight my end in the demo. My tabs are differentiated. I have updated my question to correct (and you can run the demo to see the issue).

Answer (score 0):

You can change ratio from 0.1 to 1:

```js
            $(function () {
                let ratio = 0.6; // From 0.1 to 1
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    let sections = $('.sections section');
                    let scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    let screen_height = $(window).height();
                    $.each(sections, function () {
                        let top = $(this).offset().top;
                        let calc = (top - scrollTop) / screen_height;
                        if (calc >= (ratio * -1) && calc <= ratio) {
                            let id = $(this).attr('id');
                            $("nav a").removeClass("active");
                            $("nav a[data-letter='" + id + "']").addClass("active");
                            //console.log(`${id} is Active`);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

```css
.nav {
            background: grey;
            padding: 30px 15px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .nav a {
            padding: 0 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .nav a:hover {
            background: black;
            color: white;
        }

        .nav a.active {
            background: black;
            color: white;
        }

        .sections {
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

        section {
            padding: 200px 0;
            color: red;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 50px;
        }

        section:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: black;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>

        <nav class="nav">
            <a href="#a" data-letter="a">A</a>
            <a href="#b" data-letter="b">B</a>
            <a href="#c" data-letter="c">C</a>
            <a href="#d" data-letter="d">D</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="sections">
            <section id="a">A</section>
            <section id="b">B</section>
            <section id="c">C</section>
            <section id="d">D</section>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that you have an inaccurate understanding of what `:visible` selector in jQuery selects. From [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/): "Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero." By this definition, all of the sections are "visible".

To achieve your use case you need to calculate coordinates of individual sections and compare them with scroll position in the document. The following appears to do what you are looking for ([try it out here](https://jsbin.com/qutesac/edit?html,js,output)):

```js
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        // determine element that is fully in the viewport
        const fullyVisibleSection = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section')).find((section) => {
            const topY = section.offsetTop;
            const bottomY = topY + section.offsetHeight;
            return (topY >= window.scrollY) && (bottomY <= (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight));
        });
        // only update classes if the section is fully visible
        if (fullyVisibleSection) {
            $("nav a").removeClass("active");
            // add class where id and data-letter match
            $("nav a[data-letter='" + fullyVisibleSection.id + "']").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```