# Listener for AbstractComponent that becomes visible in browser viewport with Vaadin

Tags: java, events, containers, vaadin, visible

I've got several Layout components, added as tabs, in Vaadin that execute time-consuming operations to display some values. In order to minimize the computation time I'd like to execute the time-consuming operation only if the concerning panel/layout becomes visible. I've tried common event listeners but they didn't get fired. In Swing I'm used to react on such events. But how do you do it in Vaadin?

```
    gridLayout.addComponentAttachListener(new ComponentAttachListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void componentAttachedToContainer(
                final ComponentAttachEvent event)
        {
            System.err.println("attach-listener-" + event);
        }
    });

    gridLayout.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void layoutClick(final LayoutClickEvent event)
        {
            System.err.println("layoutclick" + event);
        }
    });
```

It's important to realize a "lazy loading" for these UI container's content. I'm convinced that I'm not the only one that ever tried to realize this. What would be your approach?

Comment: It seems that Javascript misses such an event (shown/disappeared in viewport) for arbitrary DOM elements. That's why Vaadin has troubles to realize this event on components: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462138/js-event-listener-for-when-element-becomes-visible

Answer (score 1):

In case you are actually using `TabSheet` you can first add empty layouts on the tabs and then listen for [tab selection change events](https://vaadin.com/api/7.2.3/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#addSelectedTabChangeListener%28com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener%29). There you can fill the empty layout with your costly operations.