# Add class on html element when it gets visible on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to add class to the element when it gets visible on screen when scrolling:

```
<button class='btn btn-default' >
   Hello
</button>
```

I want to add class to `'btn-default'` when the button gets visible on screen after scrolling or when page reloads.

Comment: _gets visible_ ? Can you explain how does it get visible ?

Comment: I mean when the button gets visible on screen through scrolling or when page reloads

Comment: What is the sense? Why do you need this? Provide the usage example.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, may be some animations!

Comment: You can use `onscroll` and `onload` events to achieve this..

Comment: @RayonDabre Yeah. I do not say that there is no sense. I just want to know why the OP wants to do this. Probably, in his case, it can be achieved in other way.

Comment: @RayonDabre I think you have used the wow jquery plugin. when we scroll down the page the selected 'div' animates. Same i want to add class to btn when it gets visible on screen after scrolling.

Comment: You can use ".load(function(){}" . Load event is sent to an element when the element itself and all the sub-elements have been loaded. Something like this: 
$(".btn").load(function(){
 $(this).addClass("btn-default");
});

Comment: If you have control over the function which decides it's visibility then just add a callback to that function. Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462138/js-event-listener-for-when-element-becomes-visible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try visible selector as in :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if ($(".btn").is(':visible')){
        $(".btn").addClass("btn-default");
    }
});
```

Comment: I modified my answer as per @Ravimallya. I initially didnt use "on scroll" as the question did not say that the person needed the element to be visible on scroll. :)

Comment: OP didn't add it in question, but in comment he mentioned. So added my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've to use jquery `$(element).is(':visible')` to check whether an element is visible in an HTML document.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/mhfcwyk8/1/)**

This is the snippet where it will add a class when document ready and when scrolled to the element.

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('#testElement').is(':visible')) {
    $('#testElement').addClass('red');
  }
});
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var $elem = $('#testElement1');
  var $window = $(window);

  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
  if (elemBottom < docViewBottom) {
    alert('hi')
    $('#testElement1').addClass('red');
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testElement" class="btn btn-default">
  Hello
</button>
<div style="height:400px">Some content</div>
<button id="testElement1" class="btn btn-default">
  Hi
</button>
```

Answer (score -6):

Normally you can add and remove class below code but first you add(include) any jquery min js

```
Add class: $('.Yourclassname').addClass('addclassname'); 

Remove Class: $('.Yourclassname').removeClass('removeclassname');
```