# How can I check every 5 seconds to see if Divs are visible and if so, show another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to check if all divs are visible, and if they are then to not show a div which contains a submit button. All the divs are basically validators that only show if there are errors. This is because I cannot use Jquery validator. I am doing this on a timer so it can check every 5 seconds, instead of using a button. Also - It is not possible to link the validation to the button.

What I've tried:
JS:

```
     window.setInterval(function(){
     if ($(".needData:hidden").length == 0) {
         $(".answer").show();
         $(".pleaseval").hide();

    }else{
         $(".answer").hide();
         $(".pleaseval").show();
             }       
        }, 5000);
```

HTML:

```
div id="myClass" class="needData" style="display:none">hidden</div>
div id="myClass1" class="needData" style="display:none">hidden</div>
div id="myClass2"  class="needData" style="display:none">hidden</div>
div id="myClass3" class="needData" style="display:none">hidden</div>
<div class="pleaseval">Please fill out form</div>

<div id="answer" class="answer"><button>button</button></div>
```

Comment: You should consider performing the given action on Event, rather than polling to check a given state. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462138/js-event-listener-for-when-element-becomes-visible) might be useful.

Comment: I should, but for stupid reasons which take way to long to explain, I cannot

Comment: Not seeing any div with class answer & pleaseval. Please update the snippet. Also use :visible instead of :hidden

Comment: done, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You don't need Validator. Just do your check on change of the input values, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You target `.answer` in js but don't you actually need `#answer`?

Like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
     if ($(".needData:visible").length == 0) {
         $("#answer").show();
         $(".pleaseval").hide();

    }else{
         $("#answer").hide();
         $(".pleaseval").show();
    }       
}, 5000);
```

Here you can see test of it https://jsfiddle.net/8bL8ywzu/

And if you remove `style="display:none"` from one element you'll see that after 5s button will be hidden.

Comment: What is diffrence between your code and code in question unless your changed `.answer` to `#answer`?

Comment: @Mohammad question is edited in the meantime. Except that instead of `:hidden` I set `:visible`

Comment: There isn't any difference really, as I was refering to class and id correctly in my code, I just messed up puting it on stackoverflow. Ill see if theres some other issue

Comment: @Stacker So this isn't this what you need? Every 5s it checks if all elements are hidden and if not it hides button.

Comment: Yes, that works in fiddle and I'm just trying to get it working on my code. Ill mark it correct