# Event each time component becomes visible

Tags: events, angular, typescript

Is there a way in Angular2 to have an event fired when my component becomes visible?
It is placed in a tabcontrol and I want to be notified when the user switches. I'd like my component to fire an event.

Comment: If this is a tab control you've implemented, surely you could add an event emitter and emit in the same place you change tab?

Comment: Well I use primeng's tab control, and the only event that exists is called before the change, so the control is not yet visible at this time :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What I finally did (which is not very beautiful but works while I don't have a better way to do it...) is to use the `ngAfterContentChecked()` callback and handle the change myself.

```
@ViewChild('map') m;
private isVisible: boolean = false;
ngAfterContentChecked(): void
{
    if (this.isVisible == false && this.m.nativeElement.offsetParent != null)
    {
        console.log('isVisible switched from false to true');
        this.isVisible = true;
        this.Refresh();
    }
    else if (this.isVisible == true && this.m.nativeElement.offsetParent == null)
    {
        console.log('isVisible switched from true to false');
        this.isVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is m.nativeElement ?

Comment: @dGayand nativeElement points to the native DOM HTML element.

Comment: This may work, but consider that ngAfterContentChecked is been executed at any kind of event in father or child trhee component. Its maybe called 100 times and you only really require 1 execution of this 100 times

Comment: very strange that Angular framework is not providing a solution. ngAfterContentChecked didn't work for me. It was not triggered when componant was removed from DOM ex: with ngIf. 


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent

Answer (score 13):

There is no such event, but if you're using a tab control, the proper way to do this would be to create a tab change `@Output` for your tab control if it's custom, otherwise, most tab controls (like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs)) have some tab change event as well.

If your component has to be aware of this, you can use this tab change event to detect which tab is visible, and if you know which tab is visible, you also know if your component is visible or not. So you can do something like this:

```
onTabChange(event) {
    this.currentTab = /** Get current tab */;
}
```

And then you can send it to your component itself if you have an input:

```
@Input() activated: boolean = false;
```

And then you can apply it with:

```
<my-component [activated]="currentTab == 'tabWithComponent'"></my-component>
```

Now you can listen to `OnChanges` to see if the model value `activated` changed to `true`.

---

You can also refactor this to use a service with an `Observable` like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class TabService {
  observable: Observable<any>;
  observer;

  constructor() {
    this.observable = Observable.create(function(observer) {
      this.observer = observer;
    });
  }
}
```

When a component wishes to listen to these changes, it can subscribe to `tabService.observable`. When your tab changes, you can push new items to it with `tabService.observer.next()`.

Comment: That's a great idea, however I don't thnik it work in my case because the tabcontrol I use is from primeng and they only provide an event on tab change _before_ the tab has actually changed => my component is not visible at this time...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `ngAfterViewInit()` callback

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

**Update**

The new Intersection Observer API can be used for that
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670818/217408

Comment: it doesn't seem to fit my needs, I placed a log inside this callback, and it's only called once (regardless if my component is visible or not).

Comment: Angular doesn't have a way to know when a component becomes visible if it's just hidden behind another DOM element.. If you use `*ngIf=""` to show/hide, then component when the tab is selected or deselected, then `ngAfterViewInit()` is called every time.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit is called after the view is initialized, not after the element is viewed

Answer (score 1):

Best way to work around this limitation of Angular is to use a shared service that provides a Subject your component can subscribe to. That way new values could be pushed onto the Observable and the components which subscribe get the newest data and can act accordingly.

Fyi: The difference between a normal Observable and a Subject is that a Subject is multicast whereas an Observable could only be subscribed to by one Subscriber.

As a small example I show you a possible implementation of a shared-service and following the subscription inside the component that needs this new data.

Shared-service:

```
// ...

private actualNumberSubject = new Subject<number>()
public actualNumber$ = this.actualNumberSubject.asObservable()

/**
 * @info CONSTRUCTOR
 */
constructor() {}

/**
 * @info Set actual number
 */
setActualNumber(number: number) {
    this.actualNumberSubject.next(internalNumber)
}

// ...
```

Push new value onto the subject from anywhere where shared.service is imported:

```
// ...
this.sharedService.setActualNumber(1)
```

Subscribe to sharedService.actualNumber$ in component to process/display that new data:

```
// ...
this.sharedService.actualNumber$.subscribe(number => {
    console.log(number)
    
    // e.g. load data freshly, etc.
})

// ...
```

Comment: Perfect for async response dependencies, where features within other components need to be updated to match a new state. Such as account or environment change events.

Answer (score 0):

For those watching at home, you can now use `ngAfterContentInit()` for this, at least on Ionic anyway.
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score -2):

I have the same purpose and cannot get a satisfy approach to it. The first answer will call so many times.
There is a compromised way I used, of course, not elegant either.
In parent component, I set a method:

```
parentClick() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // TO-DO 
    This.commonService.childMethod();
  }, time);
}
```

Maybe the method not accurate in time, but in some way, you reach  the destiny.