# ngOnit() of the component is not called again when previously page was refreshed while on component view

Tags: angular

I have two components: Component 1 and Component 2

Component 2 can be accessed via Component 1, from a button:

```
<ion-button [routerLink]="['/urlofComponent1'] [color]="'white'">Request </ion-button>
```

I have set a function in Component 2, to redirect user to 'Component 1' on page refresh, via:

```
this.router.navigate(['/urlofComponent1']);
```

When component 2 is already opened and page is refreshed, user is redirected to Component 1.

When I access Component 2 now, via the button, ngOnit() of Component 2 is not called.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no lifecycle hook that fit your needs. you should write your own hook. Like what ionic team built [ionViewDidEnter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/):

> Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.

Here are some example codes: [Event when component becomes visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651581/event-when-component-becomes-visible)

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using

```
this.router.navigate(['/urlofComponent1']);
```

in constructor it can ignore ngOnInit because you are redirecting to another component before this one is initialized.
You can use it at the end of your ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){

  // your code

  this.router.navigate(['/urlofComponent1']);
}
```

Comment: It is at the end of ngOnit()

Answer (score 0):

Its true because [ngOnInit] defined Doc Angular: Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input propertie and **Called once**, after the first ngOnChanges().
You can read https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks here then you will understand deep lifecle-hook.
Try the above one if you didn't understand let me know i will edit it.

Comment: Okay! Any alternative in my condition? Or it isn't possible?

Comment: you set the component 2 button redirect to component 1 or you use ngOnChange when component 2 change everything then [ngOnChange] will be called.