# Detecting that user has scrolled to the bottom of the div without scroll event?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm looking for js solution that detects when user has scrolled to the bottom of the div with `overflow: auto`.

There are plenty of solutions here on SO that describe how to achieve it with `onscroll` event, but I was wondering if this can be done this with newer technology like `IntersectionObserver` that doesn’t require attaching the scroll event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS: event listener for when element becomes visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462138/js-event-listener-for-when-element-becomes-visible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) For this

```js
const onScrollToBottom = document.getElementById('on-scroll-to-bottom')

const onIntersection = ([{isIntersecting, target}]) =>
  isIntersecting && (target.style.backgroundColor = 'green');

const io = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, {threshold: 1})

io.observe(onScrollToBottom)
```

```css
section {
  color: white;
}

#on-scroll-to-bottom {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
}

#visible {
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="visible">Visible Section</section>
<section id="on-scroll-to-bottom">On Scroll to Bottom</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! How easy is it to remove style when bottom is not visible?

Comment: You can pass multiple values to `threshold` for example: `threshold: [0, 0.5, 1]`, then check the `intersectionRatio` property on `entry`: `const onIntersection = ([{intersectionRatio, target}]) => target.style.backgroundColor = intersectionRatio > 0.5 ? 'green' : 'red'`

Comment: This won't work if an element's height is larger than the viewport height.

Comment: @asdfasdfads it does. what specifically isn't working for you?

Answer (score 4):

To solve the issue brought up by @catamphetamine that if the element is larger than the viewport it will never reach threshold 1, you could flatten the parent element's bounds to just the bottom of itself and then observe for `threshold: 0` and not intersecting instead:

```js
const io = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, {
        rootMargin: '-100% 0px 0px 0px', 
        threshold: 0
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply using `IntersectionObserver` like the "accepted" answer suggests is not going to work:

```js
const io = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, {threshold: 1})
```

If the element's height is greater than the viewport height then the `threshold` won't ever be `1`.
Instead, I found a better solution for variable-height content: insert a `1px` sub-element inside the element being tracked and then track the sub-element instead of the element itself via `IntersectionObserver`. This way the `onIntersection` callback will be called when a user scrolls down to the bottom of the element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `entry.boundingClientRect` which tells bottom is in viewport or not. If bottom is less than 0, which means above the viewport, also if bottom is greater than window size, which means below the viewport, it's not in view port.

Also threshold check must be on each scroll when it's in viewport, slicing to each 10%.

```
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => { 
        const bcr = entry.boundingClientRect;
        const isBottomVisible = (bcr.bottom < window.innerHeight) && bcr.bottom;
        console.log(bcr.top, bcr.bottom, window.innerHeight, {isBottomVisible});
      });
    }, {threshold: Array(11).fill().map( (_, i) => i*.1)});
    observer.observe(this._templateContainer );
```