# I want to start JS function when I scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, animation

I have a one-page website with a section for a progress bar. I have a function for animation and all that, and I know how to start it when the page loads. But I don't know how to start it when I scroll to that section.

JS code :

```
window.onload = function() {
    move();
};

var i = 0;
function move() {
    if (i == 0) {
        i = 1;
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
        var width = 1;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
        function frame() {
            if (width >= 95) {
                clearInterval(id);
                i = 0;
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + "%";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but did you mean to run a given code when a given element appears in the viewport? In that case you might consider the HTML Intersection Observer API described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462138/event-listener-for-when-element-becomes-visible

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger on scroll, you could do that through jquery.

```
$(element).scroll(() ={
    function ()
}
```

But if you want to animate on scroll, I'd advise you to use a library called Gsap. Look in the scrollTrogger document.

Comment: absolutely zero need for jQuery for this. It's a fair enough suggestion if the OP were already using jQuery, but since there's no indication of this, your code snippet is just going to confuse things.

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the scroll event on the whole document:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  move();
});

var i = 0;

function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 95) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px;width:100%;">

<div style="height:200px">padding</div>
  <div id="myBar" style="background:green;">my bar</div>

</div>
```

Comment: When I add that then everytime I scroll animation starts. But I want just when I scroll to selected section.

Comment: Your question lacks the details to accurately answer. Which selected section?

Comment: I will try to explain better. I have portfolio website onepage. I have section for my expericance, so when I scroll there I want to see animation with my progress bars. With your soltion everytime I scroll i see animation. Img : https://imgur.com/a/RBA9eDa .

Comment: @Wikson Please edit your question and place that information there. If your question is vague, then answers will also be vague. I was assuming that you'd be able to take what I had and run with it.

Comment: @Wikson Further, please add the relevant html/css to your question.