# remove class from a div when in viewport

Tags: jquery, transition, viewport, addclass

as stated in the title, i need to add/remove a class from a div when and only when it is visible in browser viewport. what i want to do is trigger an animation removing a class and using css transitions.. i know how to do that, but i need the code snippet to remove the class when a certain div is visible to the user.

can anyone help?

i checked the onScreen plugin in another post but im a bit of a noob with js/jquery and i had some problems with that.

thanks so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045852/triggering-jquery-event-when-an-element-appears-on-screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [**"Element ‘in view’ Event Plugin"**](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/) will be easier for you to grasp.

I have written some code to fit your requirements

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/M2RzU/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myclass').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
      if (visible == true) {
        // element is now visible in the viewport
        $(this).removeClass('myclass');
      } else {
        // element has gone out of viewport
         $(this).addClass('myclass');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: i have this is "head"

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.inview.js"></script>
<script>$('.myclass').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible == true) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
    $('h2').removeClass('myclass');
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
     $('h2').addClass('myclass');
  }
});</script>

nothing gets added removed.. :\

Comment: you neeed to put it inside a document ready function, updated answer

Comment: maybe your struggling with the basics somewhere. Here is a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/M2RzU/