# jquery event handler: div becomes visible/hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a div and I'd like to have an event handler listen to when it becomes visible and hidden. How do you do that?

Thanks.

Comment: i think your question was answered already here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible) See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21242078/848034

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the callback parameter in the `show()` and `hide()` methods like this:

```
$('#myDiv').show(0, onDivShow);
$('#myDiv').hide(0, onDivHide);

function onDivShow() { //your code here }
function onDivHide() { //your code here }
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/N7UNU/

Comment: the showing of the div is controlled by an asp updateprogress control: I can't write $('#myDiv').show(0, onDivShow). I need to listen to the "div just turned visible" event.

Comment: @frenchie: there is no native event to do this in JavaScript. The only real options you have are to use a custom event that you trigger when you show or hide the items or to skip that step and do what I've done above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). You would, of course, have to fire the trigger, but that is one way to do it.