# Checking if element change state from hidden to visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [jquery event handler: div becomes visible/hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948323/jquery-event-handler-div-becomes-visible-hidden)

Can I set an event to trigger after some element is hidden and then is set to visible by js?

And also can I detect if js has added class to element?

I'm working with jQuery

Comment: Is there any way you can post some code to help us better the question fully? For the second question, you can check to see if an element has a class by using the `hasClass()` function (http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1950052/692560 there isn't a built in way of listening to classes being added/removed, but another answer from the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1950199/692560) gives a way of getting a similar effect assuming all changes to classes are done with JQUery. I can't see any DOM event that would be triggered by an element being hidden or shown either, but the same principle of overwriting JQuery functions could be applied.

Comment: if you control the code that is causing the show/hide, you should just execute your other code there.

Comment: @Thor84no: Overrideing the jquery function looks like a solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can track addition and removal of classes via events.

You can track this using the `DOMAttrModified` event - which, as the name suggests, is fired every time *any* attribute of *any* element in the DOM is modified.

In this particular case we track the modification of the `class` attribute for the element we wish to track.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/dnRUu/2/

In the demo, click the 'Toggle Class' button to add a class to the first DIV. The alert you get is fired by the `DOMAttrModified` event.

More Info Here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM_Events

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-MutationEvent

*Disclaimer*: Tested only in Mozilla Firefox!

Comment: does it work on all browsers? it didn't work on safari 6.0

Comment: Oh! Tested only on FF actually. Developed the above solution as a proof-of-concept after reading mozilla docs, so that probably explains it.. :-)

Comment: It is, but only for browsers with DOM events support, like FF, IE9+ etc.

Comment: No, you mean for browser with DOM level 2 support not DOM level 3. it's deprecated in DOM Level 3:

Comment: Yes exactly. For browsers with DOM L3 support.

Comment: Ok, this is working. How to test if it's supported?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3 it's not supported anymore!

Comment: @mgalesic - This will work only for browsers with support for DOM L3 Spec. This includes FF, IE9+ but unfortunately does not include Chrome, Safari etc.. as of now.

Comment: @Gustonez - tkx for the info.

Comment: @mgalesic - It is better not to use it as it will likely never be supported by all browsers. Maybe you should use a periodic poller/timer based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use interval to handle such event:

```
function checkIt () {
    if ($('#Element').length > 0) {
        if($('#Element').is(':hidden') == true) {
           // add class name
            alert('Element was hidden');
            $('#Element').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');

            // or toggle class name
            //$('#Element').toggleClass('className');

            // or remove class name
            //$('#Element').removeClass('className');

            // if you want to clear the interval
            //clearInterval(listenerID);
        }
    }
}

var listenerID;
$(function(){
    listenerID = setInterval(checkIt, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KFGrL/2/

To check if an element has a class name:

```
if ($('#Element').hasClass('className')) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event you could subscribe to. The best you can do is run periodically your own function to check for changes you care about..