# How do I make a custom jquery event to be triggered as an element is made visible?

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger a cutom event everytime an element is made visible .

ANy idea how i can achieve that i

Comment: Is it your code doing the showing and hiding, or do you want to catch when some other code out fo your control shows and hides things?

Comment: You must have already got a solution. But for others here's the link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible

Answer (score -1):

your question is not appropriate enough to receive answers but according to what i am guessing try this..

Once your element become visible add a class to it by using

```
$('some_element').addClass('isvisible');
```

then make a check if your element has that class isvisible than trigger your event

```
if('some_element').hasClass('isvisible'){
        // your triggger
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just trigger the event whenever you `show` or make the element `visible`. You can use `trigger` method to trigger the custom events on an element.

```
$('elementSelector').trigger('customEvent');
```