# jQuery: How to call function when element shows

Tags: jquery, bind, show

I want to call a function when a div shows (after show).

Does anybody knows how could I do this? I try to use something like that:

```
$(#someDiv).bind('show',function(){
    alert('example')
});
```

But I don't sure if I do that from correct way  or if it is possible or not achieve that. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

As of jQuery 1.7, the **.live() method is deprecated**. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It's not even an answer to the question.

Answer (score 17):

The following code (adapted from http://maximeparmentier.com/2012/11/06/bind-show-hide-events-with-jquery/) will enable you to use `$('#someDiv').on('show', someFunc);`.

```
(function ($) {
  $.each(['show', 'hide'], function (i, ev) {
    var el = $.fn[ev];
    $.fn[ev] = function () {
      this.trigger(ev);
      el.apply(this, arguments);
      return el;
    };
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This breaks chaining after `show()` or `hide()` are called

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @BrianLeishman. I've made a change to preserve chaining and a plunker to test it: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yv5nnqBI2o23mitDQI86?p=preview

Comment: I still had a problem with the updated version with chaining, specifically with the Chosen library that seems to leverage it. The problems seemed to go away if I tweak it to be "return el.apply(this,arguments);" I think you're returning the original function instead of the response?

Comment: Bad idea to trigger custom events on random elements.
If I have custom handler on some element for my custom event `show`, I don't want it triggers by someone else

Answer (score 6):

It must be done in the show() method, in its post-callback:

```
$('#someDiv').show('slide',function(){
    alert('example')
});
```

Comment: This way you are not "waiting" for the event. It's useless, for example, in case of a modal window because you are showing it right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"> </script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("#jq_message").show(function(){
            $("#jq_message").fadeOut(3000);

            $("#div2").fadeOut("slow");

            $("#div3").fadeOut(3000);
        }); 

    });

</script>

<div id="jq_message"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').live('show', function(){
    // CODE
});
```

Comment: It tried, and it doesn't seems to work. Did you manage to make it work once?

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#elementID", function ()
{
    //Whatever
});
```

Comment: Jquery mobile. Deprecated 1.4.0

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$(#someDiv).bind('show',function(){
    callFunction();
});
```

or

```
$(#someDiv).on('show',function(){
    callFunction();
});
```

function callFunction()
{
............
}

Comment: whats the difference between your code snippet and code provided by OP

$("#SF-pid-1").on('show',function(){
    alert("Jai Ho");
});  tried to call this  and this also have not worked