# Javascript event handler for flash notice in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am just wondering if there is any way to do this?

Basically, I have some javascript that I want to execute after the user has closed the flash notice which appears when the page loads. Do I have to make a custom flash notice to get an event handler on it or is there a way to get a handler on the built-in rails flash notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily bind a jquery event handler to the user clicking on the button to dismiss the flash notice..

`$().ready(function() {
  $("#button_id_that_user_clicks_to_dismiss_the_flash_notice").click(function() {
    alert("user has dismissed the flash notice")
  })
})`

your flash element is probably located in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb .. edit this file to ensure that you properly id the dismissal button

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you're using coffeescript, which is currently default in Rails:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#flash_close_button').on 'click', (ev) ->
    # close flash notice
    # do other stuff here
```

This will require you to edit the html for the flash notices. To do this without an identifier, you might want to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1225114/419017).