# is there any actual code for my pseudo code?

Tags: jquery, pseudocode

This is purely out of curiosity.

Is there any actual code for doing this in jquery?

```
$('div.withSomeclass').on('appear',function(){
  // do something
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I wasn't complete in my question

What I'm trying to do is, whenever a DOM element is added do something with it. Not only when clicking it or something like that. As soon as the element with the selector (`div.withSomeclass`) is added, I want to do something with it.

Comment: When should appear be triggered?

Comment: Please clarify what you want this to do. This could do any number of different things, we don't know what you *mean*.

Comment: Guys, I was editing. So it took me some time. Check out the edit

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can trigger your custom event with `.trigger()`

```
$('div.withSomeclass').trigger('appear');
```

Comment: maybe the same question here : [jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jQuery plugin to achieve

https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear

You can check live demo here http://morr.github.io/appear.html