# Pop-up Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any specific way to execute a JS script until a pop-up element has appeared, without using `setTimeout()`? Following are the steps for pop-up opening.

- User is on abc.com and clicks a button.
- Pop-up element appears.
- User clicks on another button in pop-up. The event handler should be specific to this click.

My current implementation is provided below.

```
$(document).on('click',function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('#pop-up').css("visibility") === "visible") {
            $('.modal-footer button').click(function() {
                // Do something;
                }
            });
        }
    },1500);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery event to trigger action when a div is made visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible)

Answer (score 1):

If you're showing bootstrap modal *(as i can infer from the boostrap classes that you've used in your code)*, then you can use `shown.bs.modal`

look at the official documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

> **shown.bs.modal**
>
> This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

*example*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Events - shown.bs.modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>The <strong>shown.bs.modal</strong> event occurs when the modal is fully shown.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    });
        $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            alert('The modal is fully shown.');
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_event_shown&stacked=h)