# How to hide and display contnet on ajax loaded data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to display and hide data which is loaded using Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/swip.php",
    data: {pid:sldnxtpst,sldnu:sldnu},
    success: function(result) {
       $('.swip').prepend(result);
    }
});
```

This data is loaded when the user scrolls to bottom.

```
<div>Loaded data on document ready</div>
<div>Loaded data on ajax </div>
<div>Loaded data on ajax </div>
<div>Loaded data on ajax </div>
```

Data I want to hide and display on click:

```
<div class=".comment-box<?php echo $sldnu; ?>"> display / Hide </div>
<div class=".comntbxfrm<?php echo $sldnu; ?>">Content </div>
```

on click on display/hide div I want to toggle ,comntbxfrm div. It's just not working with this script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var cmnbxnu = <?php echo $sldnu; ?>;
        $('.comment-box'+cmnbxnu).each(function () {
        $(document).on('click','comment-box', function(){
            alert(cmnbxnu);
            $('.comntbxfrm'+cmnbxnu).toggle();
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's confusing me. What should I do to display and hide div's on Ajax loaded data.

Comment: Do you mean something like a loading gif for user to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you post this question without rechecking it. Please take a look on your question again. May be you can provide more data on what you have tried.

May be this logic can solve your problem.

- First check if the div is visible or not, using jQuery or JavaScript.
  ( Reference: [jQuery event to trigger action when a div is made
  visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible) )
- If div is visible then change or add class `swip-active`.
- then use SCRIPT 01.
- make sure that `swip-active` class is used only once in one page

Structure of your code need to be like this:

```
<div class="swip">Loaded data on document ready</div>
<div class="swip">Loaded data on ajax </div>
<div class="swip-active">Loaded data on ajax </div>
<div class="swip">Loaded data on ajax </div>
```

**SCRIPT 01:**

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click','.swip-active .comment-box', function(){
                $('.swip-active .comntbxfrm').toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I think this simple. :) have great coding!

Comment: That's worked! Thank you Ramesh Pardhi :) But the only problem is I am not able to change the class when div is visible. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class=".comment-box<?php echo $sldnu; ?>"> display / Hide </div>
<div class=".comntbxfrm<?php echo $sldnu; ?>">Content </div>
```

You need to remove the dot from the class names in the *class* attribute, like this:

```
<div class="comment-box<?php echo $sldnu; ?>"> display / Hide </div>
<div class="comntbxfrm<?php echo $sldnu; ?>">Content </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your `html`. Besides what @miniskulljob say (which is correct) I don't see any class reference in the `html` code you are posting here.