# Jquery call function when div is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying without success to call this function when a div (`#schedule`), initially set as disabled, is shown.

```
function enable_create_btn(){
    if($('#schedule').is(":visible")) {
        $("#create_btn").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $("#create_btn").prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to trigger on show event and call this function when div is becomes visible without adding external plugins (like [this](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) solution ?)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: It seems like you are looking for something like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery#answer-1397500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery#answer-1397500)

Comment: This accomplishes your goal: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462443/693275

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery event to trigger action when a div is made visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes to the `visibility` attribute:

```
  var target = $('#schedule');
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(){
             //do stuff here
      });

      observer.observe(target, {
             attributes: true
      });
  }
```

If you're the one controlling the visibility however, this solution is kind of overkill in my opinion. The better approach is to just react to the change in the same place where you change the `visibility`

Comment: mutationObserver is more for debugging purpose