# Is there a way to track event when a particular part of page getting seen in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

For example:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
    </div>
    <div class="div5">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Imaging that the blocks are big ones, and the browser view cannot hold all of them at the same time. Is there a way if I can get idea that a particular block get displayed and viewed by user?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible

Comment: you mean this? https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#4thpage