# JQuery - trigger call on div becoming visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is shown / hidden through CSS media queries.

I want to trigger a JQuery call when this div becomes visible - triggering once if the div changes from

```
display: none;
```

to

```
display: block;
```

Is this possible to do?

Something like the onclick call, but on the div property changing to visible?

```
$(document).on('click', '#mydiv', function() {
}
```

Comment: Will that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible

Comment: Is it possible, yes. You can look into dom mutator.

Comment: @YotamSalmon not sure if this covers visible toggle using css.

Comment: Use [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) with same rule used for the `div` to become visible

Comment: @Rajesh That's why I asked if it helps. Different ways that change the CSS require different approaches for listening to them, and that's why I asked if that approach may be relevant.

Comment: None of dupes are dupe...

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATED to handle it on page load*

Use [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) with rule used for the `div` to become visible and set relevant event listener filtering by event `matches` property.

***Here an example BUT you have to use your own media queries rule.***

```
var widthMatch = window.matchMedia("(min-width:500px)");
if(widthMatch.matches) {
  divIsVisible();
}
widthMatch.addListener(function(e){
  if(e.matches) {    
    divIsVisible();
  }
});

function divIsVisible(){
  console.log('DIV is visible!')
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: I never knew something like this existed. Learned something new. +1. Just a question, is this approach also expensive like DOM mutator?

Comment: Regarding OP expected behaviour, this is for sure better and i've never heard about any performance issue regarding native `window.matchMedia()` API (there is some regarding polyfill for older browsers though)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function myFunction(){
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('foo foo') }, 2000)
}
$(document).click(function(){
$('#demo').css('display','block');
//after div is visible myFunction is triggered
myFunction();
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>click</h1>
<div id='demo' style='display:none'>
<p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$(window).resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) to detect these css `display` changes on the desired element:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var divDisplay = $('.mobileHide').css("display");
  if (divDisplay === "block") {
    $('.status').css('display', 'block');
    //do stuff
  } else {
    $('.status').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

[**See resizable fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t2161rre/1/)